# Program starts and appears in task manager, but then allocates half of my CPU and crashes

Tags: windows-8, compact-disc, gaming

The program is a CD game called CivCity: Rome (by Firefly studios, in case there are any other games with the same name). It was originally built for Windows XP, I think.

I am on a Windows 8 gaming computer, 3.1 GHz Dual core CPU with 8 GB of ram, so i doubt the problem is limitations.

I installed and ran the game the other night, and it did so without any problems. Two days later I try to boot it again, but it does not seem to start properly. I did some digging in task manager, and learned that the program seems to correctly start, but then allocates about 51% of my CPU and crashes, disappearing from task manager all together.

At first I believed it was a problem with the disc, but it does not appear so. Also, if it is any help, I tried a NoCD crack (gamecopyworld.com), but it would not start to begin with, giving me a C++ Visual library abnormal program termination error (Could this possibly be the reason it crashes, but it doesn't give an error?).

Comment: Programs do not "allocate" CPU. They *use* CPU.

Comment: Eh, kinda and kinda not. They can reserve CPU, which the system then labels as used CPU.

Comment: 51% may indicate its using *all* of one CPU

Comment: Maybe that is the problem, but I think that the problem lies in the fact that the program attempts to use that much in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you need to leverage "Compatibility mode" to use this software. Right click the desktop icon for the game and go to it's properties screen. Under the compatibility tab, check "Run this program in compatibility mode for" and select Windows XP.

After saving your changes, try opening the game again with the same desktop icon and see if you get different results.

[image]

Comment: There is not compatibility tab on my computer when i click properties. Perhaps this only works in windows 7?

Comment: Tried something similar, no effect

Comment: @mrdorkface - What exactly is "something similar" to compatibility mode which exists in all versions of Windows after Windows Vista?

Comment: I did it in a different way. There is a troubleshooting program for compatibility issues, instead of it being within properties