# Microsoft Visual C++ Library Runtime error: abnormal Program Termination

Tags: windows-7, gaming

A game I have, CivCity Rome, will not obey me.

I am on a windows 7 Pro (I think it's pro) laptop, with a 1.8 GHz processor, and 4 GB ram, 64 Bit system.

I have googled to no avail.

It usually runs from a disc, but I wanted to play it on my laptop, which does not have a disc drive. I downloaded a NoCD crack from gamecopyworld.com, but I have a legitimate copy of the disc. I did as I was supposed to, and replaced the default .exe with the one from GCW. Whenever I run the program, i get an error:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
Program C:/Program Files (x86)/Firefly Studios/CivCity Rome/CivCityRome.exe
abnormal program termination
```

I think this may be related to a previous question about CCR, where  I said that I could get the program to partially start, but then it eats up my CPU and crashes (that was on my Desktop) (link for that question is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/992503/program-starts-and-appears-in-task-manager-but-then-allocates-half-of-my-cpu-an))

Comment: This indicates a fault in the executable your using.  On the system that normally runs it from the CD does this same modified executable work?

Comment: No, but the CD doesn't work either- It crashes without giving an error window.

Comment: I didn't ask if it worked with the CD.  I asked if it worked on the system with the capability to run it from the CD with the modified executable.  If both systems generate the same error then the same problem exists on both systems.  The original executable silently crashing is a different problem.  **I answered my own question**;   You originally stated the same error happens on the other system with the modified exectuable.  This means your system is missing a required resource.  What version of the C++ Runtime is required by this program?.

Comment: I dont know what C++ runtime is required, most of the websites about this several year old game have faded away. Also, the Windows 8 computer i originally tried it on ran from the CD at first, but then quit, something that happened on the laptop i had before I got my gaming computer.

Comment: I don't know which version is required.  You need to determine that and install the required version on your system.  [Given the publication of date of the game  I would wager its 2005.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3387)

Comment: 2005 Didn't work. The NoCD crack appears to have been uploaded in 2006, but the next C++ library after 2005 is 2008.

Comment: Do you know what "abnormal program termination: might specifically mean?